# C# pass arrays to visual basic library

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net, casting

I'm trying to pass C# arrays to a Visual Basic library. This is, what the documentation says:

> 4.5.4.5 Remove    Description  Removes an OPCItem     Syntax  Remove (Count As Long, ServerHandles() As Long, ByRef Errors() As Long)
>
> Count  The number of items to be removed  ServerHandles  Array of
>   server item handles for the items processed   Errors  Array of Long’s
>   indicating the success of the individual items operation.

And the Visual Studio object catalogue shows me this method signature:

```
void Remove(int NumItems, ref System.Array ServerHandles, out System.Array Errors)
```

My code looks like this:

```
internal void RemoveItem(OpcItem item)
{
    long[] serverHandles = new long[1];
    serverHandles[0] = item.ServerHandle;
    long[] errors = new long[1];
    Array h = serverHandles.ToArray<long>();
    Array e = errors.ToArray<long>();
    this.Group.OPCItems.Remove(1, h, out e);
}
```

The compiler is happy with this, but when I call the method I get:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeArrayTypeMismatchException: Das angegebene Array hat nicht den erwarteten Typ.
   bei System.StubHelpers.MngdSafeArrayMarshaler.ConvertSpaceToNative(IntPtr pMarshalState, Object& pManagedHome, IntPtr pNativeHome)
   bei GBDAAutomation.OPCItems.Remove(Int32 NumItems, Array& ServerHandles, Array& Errors)
   bei DataLogger.DataSource.OpcDataSource.RemoveItem(OpcItem item)
```

,which states, that one of the arrays has a wrong type. Can you please enlighten me, how to pass those arrays? I'm quite new to C# and the .Net runtime, so please bear with me.

---

Edit:

Played a little around with the code. This is my current version, which still causes the same error.

```
Array serverHandles = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(long), 1);
serverHandles.SetValue(item.ServerHandle, 0);
Array errors;
this.Group.OPCItems.Remove(1, ref serverHandles, out errors);
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. You have a `long[]` which you call `ToArray<long>` on? Either way it should work. But as @Kapol answered, it might be because you didn't explicitly state `ref` in your method call. StackTrace says `ConvertSpaceToNative`-- are you sure the values in your arrays are good?

Comment: I call ToArray() to get a System.Array. If I try to pass the long[], the compiler complains about invalid method arguments. Also tried with the ref keyword, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Also, while `out`'d parameters [don't **have** to be initialized](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx) it shouldn't be a problem that they are. But perhaps try using an un-initialized array instead.

Comment: You shouldn't get a type mismatch error. I just wrote a quick test app that declares `private static void foo(System.Array arr)` and calls `foo(myLongArray)` and `foo(myArray)` which compiles and runs.

Comment: No change with an uninitilized errors array. Also, if someone is interested, this is the library I'm using: http://gray-box.net/daawrapper.php?lang=en It can be tested with the Graybox simulator available on the same site.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why the compiler is happy with your code. You need to specify the `ref` keyword in C# when passing a parameter by reference.

```
this.Group.OPCItems.Remove(1, ref h, out e);
```

Comment: OK, I changed that, but I still get the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the documentation was wrong. It has to be an int instead of long.